# how to reconstruct a reduced numpy ndarray?

Tags: python, numpy

how do I use the _reconstruct method buid into a reduced numpy ndarray?

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> v = np.random.random((5))
>>> x = v.__reduce__()
>>> x
>>> (<built-in function _reconstruct>, (<type 'numpy.ndarray'>, (0,), 'b'), (1, (5,), dtype('float64'), False, '\xae^\xe4\x03\xbd\x05\xe8?\x0ei\x97\xe30\x02\xea?F\xb8\x85\xfd\x92\xae\xe1?|\x1c20\xc1\xd3\xe2?\xe8\xfa\xfd\xdc3B\xca?'))
>>> x[0]()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: _reconstruct() takes exactly 3 arguments (0 given)
```

Comment: Please give a [mcve].  What output are you expecting?  Right now you have set `x` as a built-in function, not a value or `ndarray`.

Comment: methods starting with `__` are assumed to be private, What do you actually want to achieve ?

Comment: I want to pickle the data and later reconstruct. I guess I can use np.save() but I want the string (without going via file), I thought this will be simple, but since, as mentioned here, this is an internal method, I probably should go about this differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in `numpy/core/_internal.py`

```
# Build a new array from the information in a pickle. 
# Note that the name numpy.core._internal._reconstruct is embedded in 
# pickles of ndarrays made with NumPy before release 1.0 
# so don't remove the name here, or you'll 
# break backward compatibilty. 
def _reconstruct(subtype, shape, dtype):
    from multiarray import ndarray 
    return ndarray.__new__(subtype, shape, dtype)
```

[Internal.py](https://searchcode.com/file/75432882/numpy/core/_internal.py)

Comment: thanks, can you please show how to use it in the example i gave? how to get back v from x?

Comment: Normally we use `pickle` `dumps` and `loads`, not these low level functions.